# Truecrypt - Mount with command line options through GUI

Tags: command-line, encryption, truecrypt

I'm trying to mount a Truecrypt volume with the "Preserve modification timestamp" setting disabled. However, I only want the setting disabled for just this volumen, not all volumes. The only way I've seen how to do this is by mounting the volume from the command line. However, I'd like to stick with having Truecrypt mounting the volume automatically on logon, as a Favorite, rather than creating a batch script in the Windows Startup folder that uses the `/m ts flag`. Is there a way to insert command line option through the regular Truecrypt interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the setting you are requesting are not available through GUI on per mount level. This simply means you need to skip looking at favorites and go to main window of Truecrypt and go to Settings. In the second last group of settings ("Windows") you'll find "preserve modification timestamp on file containers".

[image: Screenshot Truecrypt settings]

Comment: Cool, yeah this was ages ago... I haven't used truecryot for a while, so it might be that they've added that option since then. Glad they did, and thanks for the update!

Comment: Well... Even though Truecrypt is a digital zombie (dead, but still living... :S), both the latest Truecrypt 7.1a and the fork Veracrypt have this option. Since you wanted this option only on one volume, I think it is fair to remind you that the setting applies for ALL volumes. However, in a stable system with not many restarts, it might not be a problem that the other volumes get an updated date.